# Fragment or Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

Hi all android noob here.

One of the difficulties I have in android is choosing what to load should I load the fragment or should I fire an activity?

My module will from a recyclerview, once user clicks on the item it will take them to another screen which contains a `viewpager` with two tabs news and topics.

for this account, should I load it via fragment or should I start another activity?

Additional question: 
in what terms should I start an activity?
in what terms should I use fragment for hoping on the next screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all see the follwing official documentation: [Navigating between sibling screens](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#within-app)

There are no ideas about what should you use activity or fragment, but if you open a fragment you have to use buttons "Up" and "Back" and then you press them you should go back to the previous activity at the same state. So if you use the fragment you have to override a lot of code for appropriate working code, so in my opinion it's better way to start new activity.

Comment: It easier but what if I want to use a drawerLayout in each activity.This is why I have two activities (with the PreferenceActivity thanks to AppCompat ^^). But I would love to know if I'm coding in a good way. One activity to manage my fragment transaction.